# (Deprecated) Fragment onOptionsItemSelected not being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

**EDIT:**
This question was for the deprecated sherlock action bar. Android support library should be used instead now

I have added an action bar menu option called share for my `fragment` which appears but the selection event is not being caught

I am adding it like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(0, 7,0, R.string.share);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.social_share).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
```

Trying to capture it in both the `fragment` and the `fragment activity` like

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 7:
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm being sent!!");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and I have `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit for actionbar sherlock use

I had to use

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
```

in the main activity to capture the menu item

Comment: Same problem and it fixed for me too thanks. Can you tell why onOptionItemSelected didn't work ?

Comment: Cause the sherlock action bar doesn't use this method

Comment: Change onMenuItemSelected to call onOptionItemSelected so your code will work when moving from ABS to appcompatlib

Comment: @nadeemgc the reason it doesn't work is because Android knows about two types of menus: Options Menu and Context Menu. Actionbar Sherlock uses the Context Menu, which calls `onContextItemSelected` instead of `onOptionsItemSelected`. The `onMenuItemSelected` simply forwards the click to the correct method, which is why it appears to work better.

Comment: @AmruE. Thank you it will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 145):

Same problems happened to me:

> onMenuItemSelected events didn't get called in Fragment

Searched google cann't find a solution, and add onMenuItemSelected method in FragmentActivity doesn't solve it.

Finally resolve it by following reference to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

> Note: If you added the menu item from a fragment, via the Fragment class's onCreateOptionsMenu callback, then the system calls the respective onOptionsItemSelected() method for that fragment when the user selects one of the fragment's items. However the activity gets a chance to handle the event first, so the system calls onOptionsItemSelected() on the activity before calling the same callback for the fragment.

Which means only if you don't have that menu item handler in onOptionsItemSelected() on the activity, the onOptionsItemSelected() on the fragment will be called.

Code as following
-----Remove the handler for **R.action.add** on FragmentActivity):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            popBackStack();             
            return true;        
        case R.id.action_search:
            searchAction();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            userLogout();
            return true;
        //case R.id.action_add:
            //return true;    
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
}
```

And the handler for **R.action.add** on Fragment looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected","yes");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            add();
            return true;    
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Finally, remember to add

```
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in your onCreate method in Fragment

Comment: For me, in order to intercept the menu click on the fragment, I had to return "false" on the onOptionsItemSelected of the FragmentActivity and on the onOptionsItemSelected of the fragment, do the desired behaviour.

Comment: fragment with setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate and public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {} method did the magic

Comment: @Felixqk I am having problem like this with Fragments. I have two fragments. But fragment 2's OnOptionsSelectedItem is not getting called. Fragment 2 is showing fragment 1's menu option.

Comment: @Roon13 Remove the super.onCreateOptionsMenu; from fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu. + setHasOptionsMenu(true); worked for me without removing Activity onOptionsItemSelected.

Answer (score 131):

I had the same problem, but I think it's better to summarize and introduce the last step to get it working:

1. Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` method in your Fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
2. Override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` (if you want to do something different in your Fragment's menu) and `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` methods in your Fragment.
3. Inside your Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method, make sure you return `false` when the menu item action would be implemented in Fragment's `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method.

An example:

## Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Do Activity menu item stuff here
        return true;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

## Fragment

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ....
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `return false` on Activity's `onOptionItemSelected` is the key. just replace `return super.onOptionItemSelected(item);`

Comment: Great answer. You should change onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) when it's in a fragment

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` is what I was looking for.
Thanks

Comment: @Marco HC I am having this problem with fragments. I have 2 fragments in Navigation drawer. Both fragments have separate menu. But Even after switching, other fragment fragment menu shows previous fragment data

Comment: The 3rd point `Inside your Activity's onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method, make sure you return false when the menu item action would be implemented in Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method` helped a lot.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have noticed that the solution people gave you was to implement the code for your menue item in the activity rather then the fragment.
I think it will look much more orgenized if you had implemented the code in the fragment rather then the activity 'cos in my opinion it looks better.
To do so, do as follows :

**Activity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);      
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {            
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.SomeIDInTheMenueOfTheActivity:
            {
               //something();
                break;
            }
            default:
             //do something default and add the code under : 
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);      
        }

  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {           
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {           
                case R.id.SomeIDInFragmentMenue:
                {             
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Now the lines (and the likes): "return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);" in the activity and fragment are super important, because as if you will follow the code in debug, you will see that the menue events functions will be called first on the Activity, and if the item did not match the id's in the activity's switch-case, the degault line : "super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);" will call the onOptionsItemSelected function on the fragment, as we wanted.
(if you have many fragments, make sure to have that line in them as well, as the calling hirarchy can be somewhat complicated).

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01), it should solve by this steps:

- If you in **Activity** Using the addMenuProvider() API directly:

  ```
  class ExampleActivity : ComponentActivity(R.layout.activity_example) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      // Add menu items without overriding methods in the Activity
     addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
          // Add menu items here
          menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
          // Handle the menu selection
          return true
        }
      })
    }
  }
  ```

- If you in Fragment Using the addMenuProvider() API

  ```
  class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()

        // Add menu items without using the Fragment Menu APIs
        // Note how we can tie the MenuProvider to the viewLifecycleOwner
        // and an optional Lifecycle.State (here, RESUMED) to indicate when
        // the menu should be visible
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                // Add menu items here
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                // Handle the menu selection
                return true
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using actionbarsherlock. This worked for me:

1) Create dummy_menu.xml menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
<item
      android:title=""
      android:showAsAction="never"
      android:id="@+id/dummyMenu"
        />
```

2) In activity inflate the menu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.dummy_menu,menu);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

3) In fragments onCreateView call setHasOptionsMenu(true) and override onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected also hide the dummyMenu like this (in fragment)

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_actions, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.dummyMenu);
    item.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

it's so simple you can do that in your fragment to make sure that your action will listen correctly:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  It was because I was overiding the wrong method

onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item)
is what I used.

Make sure you are using the right one!

Answer (score 0):

You are not chaining to the superclass in the activity methods. Please have onCreateOptionsMenu() return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu), and have onOptionsItemSelected() return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) (except for the item that you are handling, which should return true to indicate that you have handled the event)

Answer (score 0):

you must add this code `toolbar.bringToFront();` next set toolbar in your activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Yazd");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.bringToFront(); // <<= add here
         ...
```