# onOptionsItemSelected not being called from fragment master detail view

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a master detail view, with both the master and detail fragments with their own action bar menu items; the master has some and the detail has some, but the details action bar item don't call `onOptionsItemSelected` when clicked. This problem is on tablet.

On the other hand if the same code is run on a phone emulator the action bar items of the detail view work with no problem.

*menu.xml*

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/save_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Save">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/cancel_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Cancel">
</item>
```

inflater is working fine and both the fragments in master detail view have the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in their `onCreate` method.

EDIT

`onCreateOptionsMenu` in the fragment activity

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu` in the master fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.itemlistactivity_menu, menu);
}
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu` in the detail fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.addfragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    System.out.println("onCreateOptionsMenu called");
}
```

Comment: Did you override the onCreateOptionsMenu method in your FragmentActivity?

Comment: @AdriánRodríguez updated the question, thats the onCreateOptionsMenu in the fragment activity

Comment: That's the problem, I think. You have to tell what menu to load. Try this: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

Comment: Doing this is giving the detail fragments Action Bar items twice.
I have a activity with a master-detail view in it. The master fragment has its own set of Action Bar items and the detail view has its own set of Action Bar items. The Menu items of the master fragment are working without a problem but the menu items on the detail fragment are not calling the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: @AdriánRodríguez updated the question with the `onCreateOptionsMenu` of both the fragments

Comment: You could try to force it when you switch fragments calling invalidateOptionsMenu();... And if that does'nt work I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: @Eriz:hey man,i am facing the same problem,post your answer if you have found the solution.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called.) link.

It says that we can achieve the desired behaviour by not intercepting the same event in Fragment Activity (Parent Activity of Fragment).

This link shows two ways however i get my thing done by using following in FragmentActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Try it out.