# How to determine which tab is selected in FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

I am using fixed tabs + swipe inside a FragmentActivity. I have added a menu in action bar. I want that when the menu is clicked it should open class based on the current tab that is selected.

```
static TabHost myTabs;
-
-
-
myTabs = getTabHost();
```

This shows an error asking me if it shouls create a method called getTabHost(). I am assuming its because I am using FragmentActivity instead of Activity. So how do I know which tab is selected?

**EDIT**

As told below I have done this

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment){
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    tabValue=fragment.getId();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.one, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (tabValue) {
    case 0:
        Toast.makeText(BarcodeActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    case 1:
        Intent i = new Intent(BarcodeActivity.this, NewCodeAdder.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But still nothing happens when I click on the menu add option.

Comment: Which case is not working, 0 or 1?

Comment: Cos it's a fragment activity, steps are slightly different. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called

Comment: The result is still same. I think its cuz they are talking about fragments not fragmentActivity

Comment: Okay try this. Move the Toast above the `switch`. And then click the menu item, does the Toast show? If so, you will know whether onOptionsItemSelected is being called or not.

Comment: Yes it is being called.

Comment: That means the issue lies with the `tabValue`. Is this the correct value? is it blank? test it. Display the tabValue in the Toast above the switch.

Comment: it says false when I click on menu now. I have added tabvalue in place of HELLO

Comment: Is the tabvalue supposed to show the current tab number?

Comment: Isnt it supposed to do that when I have added the fucntion onAttachFragment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44001/discussion-between-vyprnoch-and-kickass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, it has everything from id to finding names of tabs:

[Get the current fragment object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750069/get-the-current-fragment-object)

Comment: please have a look at the question. I have edited and added code as you told. It isnt working.