# Cannot catch toolbar home button click event

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I've implemented the newest appcompat library and using the `Toolbar` as action bar. But the problem is I cannot catch the home button / hamburger icon click event. I've tried and looked everything but doesn't seem to find a similar problem.

This is my `Activity` class :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Set up the drawer.
    navDrawerFragment = 
        (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navDrawerFragment.setUp(
        R.id.navigation_drawer, 
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), 
        toolbar);
}
```

And this is my NavigationDrawerFragment class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(
            STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        fromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(currentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like 
    // to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        drawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        //mDrawerListView.setAdapter();
        //mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return drawerListView;
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    fragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main 
    // content when the drawer opens
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(
        R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view 
    // with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        getActivity(), 
        drawerLayout, 
        toolbar, 
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, 
    // open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!userLearnedDrawer && !fromSavedInstanceState) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(fragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, currentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d("cek", "item selected");
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        Log.d("cek", "home selected");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

when I clicked a menu item, the log "item selected" gets called. But when I click on the home button, it opens navigation drawer but the log "home selected" never get called. I've set `onOptionsItemSelected` method inside my `Activity` as well, but it still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

If you want to know when home is clicked is an `AppCompatActivity` then you should try it like this:

First tell Android you want to use your `Toolbar` as your `ActionBar`:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then set Home to be displayed via `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled` like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Finally listen for click events on `android.R.id.home` like usual:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Timber.d("Home pressed");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

If you want to know when the navigation button is clicked on a `Toolbar` in a class other than `AppCompatActivity` you can use these methods to set a navigation icon and listen for click events on it. The navigation icon will appear on the left side of your `Toolbar` where the the "home" button used to be.

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_nav_back));
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("cek", "home selected");
    }
});
```

If you want to know when the hamburger is clicked and when the drawer opens, you're already listening for these events via `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed` so you'll want to see if those callbacks fit your requirements.

Comment: Tried the first part before, but it's not working. Tried the second part, and it works. But the icon doesn't change if I register the toolbar with nav drawer. One more question, is there any replacement for setDrawerIndicatorEnabled for this? I've tried with this new nav drawer and getting error. Thank u

Comment: Second solution is working. But how can we detect home button clicked and drawer button in second solution. When i m clicking drawer icon it is not opening the drawer.

Comment: When you setNavigationOnClickListener for toolbar then you lose "native" drawer behaviour :(

Comment: So now we need a separate click listener when before in fragments we could check for android.R.id.home in onOptionsItemSelected()? That's really very annoying

Comment: re: Toolbar, if you set a new NavigationOnClickListener (using setNavigationOnClickListener) you can reinstate the NavDrawer later when appropriate by calling setDrawerListener again with your ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: @straya This saved me after many hours of bashing my head against the wall. Setting the listener again was the missing piece. Thank you!

Comment: isn't ActionBarActivity deprecated?

Comment: @gerfmarquez I suppose this post was written before. You should use AppCompatActivity instead.

Comment: @MrEngineer13 Do you know the `id` of the `mNavButtonView` ? :)

Comment: How to set the home icon back to the original back arrow?

Answer (score 25):

```
    mActionBarDrawerToggle = mNavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBarDrawerToggle();
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // event when click home button
        }
    });
```

in mycase this code work perfect

Comment: You are really great, it worked, I never thought that i could able handle toolbar back button through DrawerToggle..

Comment: To have ActionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener working one must first call this:          mActionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); and manage the click events himself. (open/close drawer on click)

Answer (score 13):

This is how I do it to return to the right fragment otherwise if you have several fragments on the same level it would return to the first one if you don´t override the toolbar back button behavior.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do we have "Override" click Method in Kotlin?

Comment: @AkhilaMadari try something like this in Kotlin: val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            /*do something you want*/
            finish()
        }

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct solution with support library 21 is the following

```
// action_bar is def resource of appcompat; 
// if you have not provided your own toolbar I mean  
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    // change home icon if you wish
    toolbar.setLogo(this.getResValues().homeIconDrawable());
    toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //catch here title and home icon click                          
        }                       
    });                 
}
```

Comment: in `this.getResValues().homeIconDrawable()`, Who is `this`?

Comment: This is an activity. Getresvalues is my method,so its not relevant here. Setlogo accepts a drawable resource id.

Comment: this will handle user click at any where at whole toolbar , I dont think this what he was asking about

Answer (score 2):

> I have handled back and Home button in Navigation Drawer like

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        resetActionBar();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //showing first fragment on Start
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).replace(R.id.content_fragment, new FirstFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //listener for home
        if(id==android.R.id.home)
        {  
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                onBackPressed();
            else
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView);
            return  true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) 
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       else 
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Begin the transaction

        Fragment fragment = null;
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (id == R.id.nav_companies_list) {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            // Handle the action
        } 


        // Begin the transaction
        if(fragment!=null){

            if(item.isChecked()){
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
            }else{
                    removeAllFragments();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE).replace(R.id.WikiCompany, fragment).commit();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }

            }else{
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE).replace(R.id.WikiCompany, fragment).commit();
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void removeAllFragments(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.WikiCompany, fragment).addToBackStack("")
                .commit();
    }


    public void updateDrawerIcon() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i("", "BackStackCount: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
                    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                    else
                        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    public void resetActionBar()
    {
        //display home
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

and In each `onViewCreated` I call

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).updateDrawerIcon();
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("List");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented it pre-material design and it seems to still work now I've switched to the new `Toolbar`. In my case I want to log the user in if they attempt to open the side nav while logged out, (and catch the event so the side nav won't open). In your case you could not `return true;`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (!isLoggedIn() && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        login();
        return true;
    }
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Ah I forgot I discovered I was unable to catch the home button click in a fragment, I asked a question here and suggested a workaround which was to manually pass the event onto all of your fragments. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21938419/1007151

Answer (score 1):

I changed the DrawerLayout a bit to get the events and be able to consume and event, such as if you want to use the actionToggle as back if you are in detail view:

```
public class ListenableDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    private OnToggleButtonClickedListener mOnToggleButtonClickedListener;
    private boolean mManualCall;

    public ListenableDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ListenableDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ListenableDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the listener for the toggle button
     *
     * @param mOnToggleButtonClickedListener
     */
    public void setOnToggleButtonClickedListener(OnToggleButtonClickedListener mOnToggleButtonClickedListener) {
        this.mOnToggleButtonClickedListener = mOnToggleButtonClickedListener;
    }

    /**
     * Opens the navigation drawer manually from code<br>
     * <b>NOTE: </b>Use this function instead of the normal openDrawer method
     *
     * @param drawerView
     */
    public void openDrawerManual(View drawerView) {
        mManualCall = true;
        openDrawer(drawerView);
    }

    /**
     * Closes the navigation drawer manually from code<br>
     * <b>NOTE: </b>Use this function instead of the normal closeDrawer method
     *
     * @param drawerView
     */
    public void closeDrawerManual(View drawerView) {
        mManualCall = true;
        closeDrawer(drawerView);
    }


    @Override
    public void openDrawer(View drawerView) {

        // Check for listener and for not manual open
        if (!mManualCall && mOnToggleButtonClickedListener != null) {

            // Notify the listener and behave on its reaction
            if (mOnToggleButtonClickedListener.toggleOpenDrawer()) {
                return;
            }

        }
        // Manual call done
        mManualCall = false;

        // Let the drawer layout to its stuff
        super.openDrawer(drawerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void closeDrawer(View drawerView) {

        // Check for listener and for not manual close
        if (!mManualCall && mOnToggleButtonClickedListener != null) {

            // Notify the listener and behave on its reaction
            if (mOnToggleButtonClickedListener.toggleCloseDrawer()) {
                return;
            }

        }
        // Manual call done
        mManualCall = false;

        // Let the drawer layout to its stuff
        super.closeDrawer(drawerView);
    }

    /**
     * Interface for toggle button callbacks
     */
    public static interface OnToggleButtonClickedListener {

        /**
         * The ActionBarDrawerToggle has been pressed in order to open the drawer
         *
         * @return true if we want to consume the event, false if we want the normal behaviour
         */
        public boolean toggleOpenDrawer();

        /**
         * The ActionBarDrawerToggle has been pressed in order to close the drawer
         *
         * @return true if we want to consume the event, false if we want the normal behaviour
         */
        public boolean toggleCloseDrawer();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach we could do is change the home icon to a known icon and compare drawables (because  android.R.id.home icon can differ to different api versions

so set a toolbar as actionbar
SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);

```
_toolbar.NavigationIcon = your_known_drawable_here;

   for (int i = 0; i < _toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                View v = _toolbar.GetChildAt(i);
                if (v is ImageButton)
                {
                    ImageButton imageButton = v as ImageButton;

                    if (imageButton.Drawable.GetConstantState().Equals(_bookMarkIcon.GetConstantState()))
                    {
                       //here v is the widget that contains the home  icon you can add your click events here 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to put the icon using:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_home);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And then listen to click events with default onOptionsItemSelected and android.R.id.home id

Comment: This will not worked. `android.R.id.home` never fire

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a Xamarin implementation (since events are done differently in C#), I simply created this `NavClickHandler` class as follows:

```
public class NavClickHandler : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
{
    private Activity mActivity;
    public NavClickHandler(Activity activity)
    {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)mActivity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
        {
            drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
        }
        else
        {
            drawer.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, assigned a custom hamburger menu button like this:

```
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        this.drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;
        this.drawerToggle.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.MenuButton);
```

And finally, assigned the drawer menu toggler a ToolbarNavigationClickListener of the class type I created earlier:

```
        this.drawerToggle.ToolbarNavigationClickListener = new NavClickHandler(this);
```

And then you've got a custom menu button, with click events handled.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        //You can get 
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Add below code to your onCreate() metod

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answer provided by [MrEngineer13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26636045/1467923), there is also another possible reason why the click event might not have been captured in the `onOptionsSelected` method. Your `DrawerLayout` may have overlayed your `Toolbar`'s interface component in the layout XML file. Therefore, whenever you attempt to click the Home button, you're only clicking the `DrawerLayout`, but not the Home button that's located beneath it.

All you have to do now is rearrange your `Toolbar` in the corresponding layout XML file so that it is not blocked by any other UI component.

Programmatically, I did attempt to call the `bringToFront()` method on the `toolbar` (`toolbar.bringToFront()`). However, in my app's context, it does not seem to be the solution.