# Clicking hamburger icon on Toolbar does not open Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have a simple `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and all I am trying to do is to open a NavigationDrawer by pressing the "hamburger" icon in the top left corner. The "hamburger" button is visible, and when I start to pull from the left I see the animation on the button but pressing the button does not open/close the NavigationDrawer as I expect. I have followed the [Google Documentation][1] and still am not able to figure this out. Sorry for any confusion, below is the *simplified* code I am currently attempting to use:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("NICK", "button button button..................");
        }
    });

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        NavigationView n = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav);
        mDrawerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("NICK", "button button button..................");
            }
        });

        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        n.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    ////.......

                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();  // CLOSE DRAWER
                return true;
            }
        });

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d("NICK","CWECNEWKVNERIPNVIEWNFVIPEWNVIPEWNVPIEWNVPIEWNVPIEWNVPIRWNVPRWVPO");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  // OPEN DRAWER
            Log.d("NICK","CWECNEWKVNERIPNVIEWNFVIPEWNVIPEWNVPIEWNVPIEWNVPIEWNVPIRWNVPRWVPO");
            return true;

    }
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

}

And as it is I do not get any of the log debug statements when running.

This is essentially the issue I have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26636045/1489990. I've followed this and it just doesn't work.

It is my understanding that `setNavigationOnClickListener` is called when the hamburger icon is pressed, and this is where I am focusing my efforts is to get the event handled properly because when I press the button I do not get my log statement. Let me know if this idea is incorrect. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

My Layouts:

`ActivityMain.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/d"
android:background="@drawable/home_wall">




<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/trans2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="300dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/d8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:background="#dd2c00" android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Purchases"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/start_button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Store"
            android:id="@+id/Purchases"
            android:background="#ff6e40" android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_above="@+id/instructions_button6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="98dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Help"
            android:id="@+id/instructions_button6"
            android:background="#dd2c00" android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:background="#ff3d00"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Achievements"
            android:id="@+id/Scores"
            android:background="#ff6e40" android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Purchases"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/start_button" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome to the quiz!"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />


        <!-- sign-in button -->
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!-- sign-out button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign Out"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="#dd4b39"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/nav"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`Drawer.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:title="Google Play Games"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Sign_in_drawer"

            android:icon="@drawable/games_controller_grey"
            android:title="Sign in" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ach"
            android:icon="@drawable/games_achievements"
            android:title="Achievements" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Start a Quiz"

   android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/quizStart25"

            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"
            android:title="25 Questions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/quizStart10"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"
            android:title="10 Questions" />
    </menu>
</item>

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gallery"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_library_white_48dp"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toc_white_48dp"
        android:title="Statistics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/store"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_white_48dp"
        android:title="Store" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_48dp"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_white_48dp"
        android:title="About" />

</group>

<item android:title="Support">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/help_drawer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_white_48dp"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/report"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_report_problem_white_48dp"
            android:title="Contact Developer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/GPlusCommunity"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_g_white_normal"
            android:title="Google+ Community" />

    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In your ActivityMain.xml, the toolbar is outside of the DrawerLayout. That's the problem. If you want Toolbar to interact with DrawLayout, **Toolbar needs to be a child of DrawerLayout**.

To fix the problem, make DrawerLayout the root of your activity. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). The relevant quote is:

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the
>   DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another
>   view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

So basically, structure your ActivityMain.xml to be something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...>

    <RelativeLayout ...>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar .../>

        <!-- Your other content goes here -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView .../>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

That should take care of the problem.

Comment: I have tried exactly this and I even inserted log statements inside `onOptionsItemSelected` and they are never shown, indicating this method is never reached. As it is now I have `onOptionsItemSelected` outside of my `onCreate` method if that matters. Still haven't found a solution

Comment: @ez4nick, see my updated answer. Are you extending `ActionBarActivity` by any chance?

Comment: I am extending `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Please remove all the toggle code and then re-post your updated code in your question. I have no idea what code you're using at this point.

Comment: See updated post. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you for still trying to assist me.

Comment: I have tried this and it gives the same results as before. What I do not understand is why my log statements are not visible from inside `onOptionsItemSelected` when I press the hamburger button. This means `onOptionsItemSelected` is not being called as it should be. I must be missing something else that is causing this problem.

Comment: Did you run the exact code that I posted? Make sure you're copying it exactly as-is, and not just modifying or appending it your existing code. I've run the posted code and it works fine. Also, I see those log lines when clicking the hambuger icon. If you're running this _exact_ code and it's still not working, then I'm afraid I can't help any more. It must be something really off with your project, since this is really standard Nav Drawer stuff.

Comment: I just ran the exact code from your post and had the exact same results as before, the log statements do not appear. This must be a more complicated issue perhaps with Android Studio. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: @ez4nick, One last thing. Can you post your xml layout and menu? Maybe there's something amiss there. Specifically, post layout that contains R.id.my_toolbar, R.id.drawer, and R.id.nav, then post your menu R.menu.drawer.

Comment: It was that last one that did it for me. I was missing that I had to wrap the tool bar code in a relative layout, so that it would be happy inside the drawer layout.

Answer (score 30):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected` method and use below

```
if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){ // use android.R.id
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to sync the drawer toggle:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

EDIT: That code is working for me (copied from your post)

```
public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);
        setupDrawer();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    private void setupDrawer() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:text="DRAMER MENU" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But if you are using the new `NavigationView`, then you don't need the toggle etc. [Here is a good example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/MainActivity.java) how to use it.

Comment: I am using the new `NavigationView`, and I tried following the link you provided (See Update 2) and never receive confirmation that the button  was pressed. I am assuming this is where the NavigationDrawer is actually opened/closed

Comment: Then no need to setup a `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it by giving openable which is drawerLayout to navigateUp function.

More info [navigateUp Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#navigateUp(androidx.navigation.NavController,%20androidx.customview.widget.Openable))

```
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.host_fragment)
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,drawer_layout)
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow ! Could you add a bit of explanation to your answer ? So people would know why it will work with your code.

Comment: Yep, that solved the issue. I've deleted this automatically added by Android Studio method and hamburger icon stopped working, adding it back solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If it helps somebody, to me it happened the same because of the stupid error of calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` two times. Just call it once in onCreate method and never again. My mistake was I called it later in another method.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and implement `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Toolbar DOES NOT have to be within a DrawerLayout, it's not likely to be the cause of this issue.  `toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` looks for the ID of the item selected and if it is `android.R.id.home` then the drawer's visibility is toggled.  Thus Toolbar, or any View that creates a Home MenuItem, can be placed anywhere in your layout.

Within your activity:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

private void setupDrawerToggleInActionBar() {
    // assuming a Toolbar has been initialized in your onCreate
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // setup the action bar properties that give us a hamburger menu
    ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    // the toggle allows for the simplest of open/close handling
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                                       drawerLayout,
                                       R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                                       R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    // drawerListener must be set before syncState is called
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // This is required to make the drawer toggle work
    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * if you have other menu items in your activity/toolbar 
     * handle them here and return true
     */

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply call function onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) of ActionBarDrawerToggle class on activity options menu managing function like below.

```
mDrawerToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_drawer_accessbility_drawer_open,
            R.string.nav_drawer_accessbility_drawer_close);


 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final android.view.MenuItem item) {
    navigation().getOptionsMenuInflater(this).closeSearchView();
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this behavior.
    mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

OR

override onOptionsItemSelected of activity like below

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        toggle();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 private void toggle() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the drawer toggle you need to set "display home as up" to false:
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Comment: Tried this and it did not solve my issue. Same issue as before.

Answer (score 1):

As i have no specific answer to your problem, i want to suggest a completely different approach:

In my projects im using the [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) developed by Mike Penz.
Its looks really nice, is easy to implement, and there is not much you have to worry about.

So if you cant find a solution for your problem, you could give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, follow instruction provided by accepted answer.

Then Make sure you assign right constructor for toggle -
i.e,

```
val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.root, toolbar, R.string.OpenDrawer, R.string.CloseDrawer)
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
toggle.syncState()
```

wher drawerLayout is `val drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer)`

As there are two type of constructor for `ActionBarDrawerToggle()`

```
1 - ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    Activity activity,
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
    @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
    @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes
)

2- ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    Activity activity,
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
    Toolbar toolbar,
    @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
    @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes
)
```

Use second option to assign **toggle** to your **toolbar**.

You can read official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle)

Answer (score 0):

While accepted answer here works alright however, as they say "Prevention is better than cure".. Adding  mDrawerToggle.syncState(); in onPostCreate and onConfigurationChanged() wroks much better as answerd by @mbmc above:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of different problems I found a way to make it work putting Toolbar Widget inside AppBarLayout.

Be sure that there is no other layout on top of widget toolbar!

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawable_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**

          <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

          </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
         </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>**

        .... YOUR LAYOUT ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk why...but changing return value to false rather than true fixed the ham Icon for me. on onOptionItemSelected override method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.logout){
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logout Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No setting to update! Will be available later...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true; // here change this to false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above answer works, please cross check again,

First you need to call setSupportActionBar(toolbar); and then do the necessary work for nav drawer. I wasted my 2 hours because of this silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, it did not occur on all fragments. It occurred on one particular fragment.

Firstly, please follow @hungryghost 's answer mentioned above. Then do the following.
Adding the following piece of code helped the drawer open on click of the hamburger icon. It worked flawlessly for me. Thank you very much. :) My sincere apologies if this isn't the right way.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();        
        if(itemId == android.R.id.home){
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                    || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution to this problem is to call the setSupportActionBar(toolbar) method before the navigation drawer functions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31055906)

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm missing this one outside of the onCreate method.**

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```