# Can`t catch appcompat 23 toolbar home/up button click event

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

Here is my activity on create

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // set subtitle if there is a filter
    toolbar.setSubtitle(MySharedPref.getStringTitile(this));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, RealtyListFragment.newInstance("test", "test"))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

}
```

And then in onOptionsItemSelected i got nothing when i hit HOME/up button.

```
 Log.d("!!!!!!!!!YEP","YEP");
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        FilterDialogFragment dialogFragment = new FilterDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        return true;
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.d("!!!!!","Home pressed");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

And in my way this does not help at all.

```
@Override
```

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Timber.d("Home pressed");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot catch toolbar home button click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event)

Comment: the correct answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824324/clicking-hamburger-icon-on-toolbar-does-not-open-navigation-drawer