# Does anyone have any idea why I can't press my menu button after entering the login screen?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with Java. I am trying to create a simple android app and I get a problem with the navigation menu button. I think the problem is the way that the function is set up and I have looked into threads and synchronize but that doesn't work either this is the code that has the problem.

```
loginScreen.java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import static android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE;
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService;

public class loginScreen extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_screen, container, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboardFrom(getContext(), getView());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

```
MainActivity.java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_fragment, new MainFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.login){
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new loginScreen());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            hideKeyboard(this);

        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.register){
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new registerScreen());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }


}
```

On the actual build once I go to the login screen, I can no longer just press the menu button I have to click and drag for it to open. If the information I have provided is a bit vague I'm sorry I wasn't sure what to include.

```
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawyer_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by menu button.. is it the `NavView` menu when you hit the drawer burger ? or is it the overflow options menu?

Comment: Sorry it's the NavView

Comment: Do you have more items than `login` & `register` in the navView menu ?

Comment: Yeah i have two other items but they are just buttons at the moment no java or xml yet for them.

Comment: So, now the issue on which buttons, login/register .. or the other buttons ?

Comment: The problem is with the button that opens the menu and it only happens after i open the login view

Comment: the top left burger button ?

Comment: Yeah that's it.

Comment: can you show the layout of the mainActivity

Comment: I've added the activity_main.xml above the only MainActivity is the java file.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue .. but try to play with `setSupportActionBar()`.. try to use the default actionbar and see .. also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824324/clicking-hamburger-icon-on-toolbar-does-not-open-navigation-drawer