# ActionBarDrawerToggle with AppCompatActivity and Toolbar Back button with Fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, actionbardrawertoggle, drawertoggle

I am using the ActionBarDrawerToggle with NavigationView. My content is displayed using fragments.

I am following [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event) to get the back button press to work but control never flows to `onOptionsItemSelected`.

This is my MainActivity.class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawerContentDescRes, R.string.closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        removeFragmentFromBackstack();
        updateToolbarWithHomeButton();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // doesn't reach here ever.
            return true;
        case R.id.action_x:
            // do something
            return true;
        case R.id.action_y:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void updateToolbarWithBackButton() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (null != mDrawerToggle && null != actionBar) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void updateToolbarWithHomeButton() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (null != mDrawerToggle && null != actionBar) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

How can I capture the Back button **<-** click from `Toolbar`?

---

## Update:

Thanks to @mike the back arrow button on the toolbar is now captured within the `onOptionsItemSelected` in my MainActivity code as updated below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.openDrawerContentDescRes, R.string.closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        removeFragmentFromBackstack();
        updateToolbarWithHomeButton();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //TODO: skip back press if fragment backstack count is 0.
            onBackPressed();
            updateToolbarWithHomeButton();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_x:
            // do something
            return true;
        case R.id.action_y:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void updateToolbarWithBackButton() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (null != mDrawerToggle && null != actionBar) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    }
}

private void updateToolbarWithHomeButton() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (null != mDrawerToggle && null != actionBar) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to fire upon clicking the toggle, remove the `toolbar` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.string.openDrawerContentDescRes, R.string.closeDrawerContentDescRes);
```

Otherwise, the toggle handles opening and closing the drawer internally, and the call to `ActionBarDrawerToggle#onOptionsItemSelected()` isn't necessary.

If you want to handle clicking the home `Button` differently depending on the current state, you'll also want to remove the `if` block that returns at the top of the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

And, you should call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` just once in `onCreate()`. You don't need to keep switching that on and off. Enabling and disabling the drawer indicator will take care of that.

Comment: I removed toolbar from new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.openDrawerContentDescRes, R.string.closeDrawerContentDescRes); but the switch case for MenuItem with id android.R.id.home does not pass. Is there a different id for Back button?

Comment: The call to `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` returns `true` when the `MenuItem`'s ID is `android.R.id.home`, so that `if` block is returning before execution reaches your `switch`. You can just move that call to your first `case`.

Comment: I've added a log statement inside the `if` block but it does not return true for `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` when I click the back button

Comment: What do you mean by back button, exactly? The toggle's arrow, or the `ActionBar`'s Up button?

Comment: When I add a new Fragment to my backstack, I execute  `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` and  `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` Now I get a button that looks like **←** which i think is the toggle's arrow.

Comment: You should call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` once in `onCreate()`. You don't need to keep switching that on and off. Enabling and disabling the drawer indicator will take care of that.

Comment: Did you understand what I mean? Move the `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` call to your first `case`, remove the `if` block, call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in `onCreate()`, and remove the other two calls to `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` in your `updateToolbarWith*()` methods.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Setting `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` once in `onCreate` along with no `toolbar` in `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s constructor worked in capturing `android.R.id.home` in the `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Ah, good. I wasn't sure if I was clear. Glad you got it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
 if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
```

from `onOptionsItemSelected()` so it will look like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // doesn't reach here ever.
        return true;
    case R.id.action_x:
        // do something
        return true;
    case R.id.action_y:
        // do something
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```