# Navigation Drawer back button Click Listener in android

Tags: android

I am using NavigationDrawer in android. its working properly. now i want to change image of NavigationDrawer backbutton so for that, i used this `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`
it hide the default backbutton image. and now change the image using this `mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`
but on click of custom navigation back button drawer not working.How to manage this?

my code is

```
 public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            is= false;
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            is= true;
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Try to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event

Comment: just put your code here.. so i can correct it..

Answer (score 0):

To change the icon of NavigationDrawer backbutton, you need to call following method, with your image resourceid:

```
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId);
```

and setDrawerIndicatorEnabled() method should not be set to false to update the icon:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

because is `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()`, is set to `false` it will do two things:

1. disables the HomeAsUpIndicator icon
2. disables the clickListener.

Also you can try it with actionbar:

The below function is added in android API level 18 and upper.

```
ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

If you use support library, try this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

> Also you can try it with Styles:

The "up" affordance indicator is provided by a drawable specified in the homeAsUpIndicator attribute of the theme. To override it with your own custom version it would be something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

If you are supporting pre-3.0 with your application be sure you put this version of the custom theme in values-v11 or similar.

if it's still not working, you can try by replacing:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
```

with:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
```

Comment: i want to open and close drawer on my custom image set in setHomeAsUpIndicator . how is it possible because  i added setDrawerIndicatorEnabled false for hide default icon

Comment: and its also disable click event

Comment: yes sir  i try it..i change the the setHomeAsUpIndicator image and setDrawerIndicatorEnabled true for clickListener but its showing default backbutton image

Comment: i done this ..now backbutton default image not showing  but my custom image not added on that place...only blank space show on there and when i clicked navigation drawer open and closed..

Comment: i am using this theme   <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"><!-- Customize your theme here. -->
           <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: @aj0822 may be your image is transparent, can you try with some different image?

Comment: i am using default ic_launcher image

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your option menu selected listener.

@Override

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```