# How to click in the Toolbar on the navigation button?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

not working for me

```
activity.findViewById(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description).performClick();
```

I set in activity

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a click on the navigation button which is located in the toolbar you need to do the following:

**Add text to the navigation button**

```
toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription("up");
```

**After finding it in the following way**

```
final ArrayList<View> outViews = Lists.newArrayList();
        activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).findViewsWithText(outViews, "up", View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        outViews.get(0).performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your stuff as `R.id.yourStuff` && check it for `android:clickable="true"` prameter (if it's not a button).

Comment: I'm writing a test in which I need to click in the toolbar on the navigation button.

Comment: Maybe this'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event

Comment: Sorry, I don't need listener, I need make click.