# Action Bar item Is Not Responding On Click in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am facing A problem ...i Created A Item on Action bar ..When I click On That Item My Item Click Button Is not Responding ..For Printing I created Toast ..To Check Resopnse
But Toast Is NOt Displaying

Here Is updated fragment class ..

```
public class Welcome extends SherlockFragment {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Button editprofile;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
     ImageView i;
    Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    ImageView frm;
    ImageLoader imageloader;
    String image_url;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome, container, false);
        final UserModel user = (UserModel) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
        frm=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_frm);
        // Button editprofile = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        //ImageView image = (ImageView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView userfullname = (TextView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.userfullname);
        TextView tv_tomeet = (TextView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.tomeet);

        TextView tv_intrseted = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.intsdin);


        int loader = R.drawable.loader;

        String UserfullName = user.getUser_Full_Name();
        String Tomeet=user.getTo_Meet();
        String Age = user.getUser_Age();
        String Gender = user.getGender();
        String IntrestedIn = user.getIntrest_In();
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String image_url=user.getUser_Image();
        userfullname.setText(UserfullName);
        tv_tomeet.setText(Tomeet);
        //image loader
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    //imageloader=new ImageLoader();

        //tv_gender.setText(Gender);
    ImageView     iv = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Picasso.with(getActivity())
    .load(image_url).transform(new RoundedImageView()).into(iv);


    frm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String image_url=user.getUser_Image();
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("UserImage", image_url);
        }
    });

        // ImageLoader class instance
        //ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());



    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
      /*  imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, Welcome.this, image);*/
        return rootView;

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                logout();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    ///Logout User And Clear Sharedpref
    public void logout(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi Logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.MyLOGINDATA
                 ,0);
                   editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                  editor.clear();
                  editor.commit();
        Intent l=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(l);
        getActivity().finish();

    }



}
```

here Is Menu Item

```
<item 
          android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/setting_iconn"
          android:title="Setting"
          android:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

I really Dont Understand What I m Doing Wrong?
please help Me

Edit

I created 
in fragment class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

onclick Not Working Stil

Comment: Why is onOptionsItemSelected not getting overridden? Also if you're doing that on a fragment make sure you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` onActivityCreated();

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called

Comment: @PedroOliveira i updated My Question ...check it

Comment: Try removing super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

Comment: @PedroOliveira ...not Working ...i removed super.oncreateoptionMenu
it showing clicked ..but not performing

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the begining of onOptionsItemSelected and check  if its getting called after you click an item in the menu

Comment: I checked it not Calling

Comment: Did you make sure you have @Override before `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira..
i updated my whole fragement class see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: After learning that you work on a `Fragment`**

Add following to your `onCreate` method of your `Fragment`

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: My Methode Is In Fragment Class

Comment: @ᏕᏗᎷᎷᎩᏇᏗᏕᏋᏋᎷ your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is in Fragment ?

Comment: call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` from onCreate method of your fragment

Comment: can I call SetHasOptionMenu From FragmentActivity ?

Comment: I tried TO call in Oncreate
Giving Error Change ...PrepareoptionMenu ..like

Comment: don't forget to add `@Override` on top of your `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {`

Comment: @Metehan I Added OverRide ...Stil Not Working in fragment ...I added  setHasoptionmenu(true) in Oncreate in fragment class

Comment: and also you shouldn't initialize actionbar item from the activity, maybe you have duplicate actionbar items

Comment: i Added 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   in fragment class

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

You forget Override, that's the reason.

**EDIT**

For menus, should did it on your FragmentActivity, not in a fragment.

But, see that link, if you want to add-it in your fragment :
[Android Options Menu in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308695/android-options-menu-in-fragment) (Marco HC reply)

Comment: You really need another utility in a fragment than fragmentActivity? Check my edit

Comment: I have SherlockFragment Activity ....I created Slide Menu ...With The HElp Of Shelock Librry 

Mentioned above is Fragment class Used In sliding Menu

Comment: Never been mentionned, can't help, never worked with that lib. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sidd is correct. You need to Override the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, Inflater) and the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem). If you want to add the override methods in a fragment or in a activity use these shortcuts to find the override methods available.

For Eclipse IDE - Alt+Shift+S
For Android Studio - Alt+Insert

Also give setHasOptionsMenu(true) after setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

with

    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
{

      menu.add(0, R.drawable.setting_iconn, R.id.action_search, "Setting").setIcon(R.drawable.setting_iconn).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This works...