# Action bar item click handler in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple 2 activity application.  The main activity populates a listFragment, and the second activity populates a fragment with fields to add a custom object (list items) to the main activity.

In the second activity I have a "save" icon in the action bar.  I'm trying to figure out how to listen for this button click in the fragment, so I can package up the textFields and pass it back to the activity via the interface.

I tried to override `onOptionItemSelected`but it doesn't ever hit.  How would I handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay, so the trick is in the fragments `onCreate` method, you have to call

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

then all you have to do is override the `onOptionsItemSelected` in the fragment, and handle the action bar click there!!

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_save : {
            Log.i(TAG, "Save from fragment");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My question is in onCreate() method only this method setHasOptionsMenu(true); need to add?

Comment: yes, and then when an item is selected it will call the override of `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: My problem was that on my Activity I was overriding the method as well...