# How to catch navigation icon click on toolbar from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I have a dialog fragment in which I have toolbar in layout. 
I want to make back button(Navigation Icon) working in toolbar and exit the fragment when clicked. But I am unable to catch the click event on the toolbar's navigation icon in the (dialog)fragment.

Here is how I am getting toolbar :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
toolbar.setTitle(itemType);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Here is my layout file for the dialog fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/panel_cyan"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewItems"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is what is have tried so far but failed **

Options item click in id R.id.home

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

setNavigationOnClick() on the toolbar :

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back clicked!",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your fragment?

Comment: Yes. I do have setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate()

Comment: If you have setHasOptionMenu true and you are overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` with super call then `onOptionsItemSelected` will be triggered. Can you please put debug point in `onOptionsItemSelected` and check if it getting called?

Comment: That is the problem. Navigation icon is not responding to clicks. I tried putting logs in onOptionsItemSelected but it is not getting triggered.

Comment: Are you returning false from `onOptionItemSelected` of the activity? If the event is not being consumed by `Activity` then only it will trigger `Fragment` event. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called

Comment: I am not using options menu in the activity. But still i tried returning false their. No luck. I guess the problem is with toolbar navigation item not receiving clicks. How to do that?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

add code block `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener` after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: @Trancer for home button approach use this in onOptionItemSelected  switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home :
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home Clicked...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break; }

Comment: @Abhishek, your approach is not working and is not right. I solve this problem: all nav icons in toolbar controlling by OS

Comment: This works for home button, you first need to set it toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable) and then you can use the listener

Comment: Yes, this is working when having a toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable) and we can set above listener too.

Comment: The **after** part is *very* important. Set the toolbar *then* add the listener.

Answer (score 28):

This works for me.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"your icon was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:

                  // do what ever you want here
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably important as well: If you use Databinding like

```
MyPojoBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setPojo(myPojo)
```

the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` (followed by setting a click listener, title, or other toolbar attributes) must come AFTER the initialization of the binding.