# Back button in action bar opening and closing NavDrawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have a nav drawer set up in my main activity.  In one of my fragments I want to hide the hamburger icon and show the back arrow (achieved)

```
   ActionBar bar = mMainActivity.getSupportActionBar();
   bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   bar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The problem is if I click on the arrow it opens the drawer.  So I added this: `mMainActivity.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`

The problem is when I add this line, nothing displays.  The drawer icon and the back or up icon.  So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.?

**EDIT**

There seems to be confusion as to what I have done and not done.  The `mMainActivity.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` was added temporarily, I removed it again as when I did, there were no icons displayed neither nav drawer or back arrow.

Below is how I handle my menu item clicks:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search_badge:
                L.i("search", "search");
                return false;


            case android.R.id.home:
                L.i("home", "home pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.action_done:

                actionDone();
                //for testing
                //checkSelectedInterests();
                //TODO: MLC
                L.i("done", "done pressed");
                break;

            default:
                ;;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

however

```
 case android.R.id.home:
                L.i("home", "home pressed");
                break;
```

is never hit

I hope this clarifies it.  So at the moment the nav drawer icon is hiding and the back arrow is displayed.  When I click the back arrow it opens the nav drawer instead of entering my switch case.

Comment: Could you post relevant code? OnClick, its content, such things.

Comment: @Messer unsure what you mean..you don't usually use onClick methods with ab menu items.  they're handled in the onOptionsItemSelected method, in which I have a switch    `case android.R.id.home:
                L.i("home", "home pressed");
                break;`    All the relevant code is posted above in the op, how I set the ab.homeenabled etc..  Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest best way to create new project and goto new > Navigation Drawer. You will get complete code.

Comment: That isn't really very helpful and pointless because it doesn't provide any sort of solution to my question

Comment: Ok, so from the begining. I assume you do call mDrawerToggle.syncState(); somewhere in your code to get the hamburger instead of the arrow in the first place, right?

Comment: sure in my MainActivity `//display the drawer symbol
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();`

Comment: I reread your question a few times and I think I get what you want to do. You have a fragment for witch you don't need your drawer at all and instead want to just go back, right?

Comment: @Messer correct. I thought that the code which I've included above would do the trick but it doesn't.  It displays the back icon but still implements the mActionBarToggle action

Comment: @Messer do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed you didn't call yourActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); whis should let you hit your case in that switch

Comment: @Messer I added that but it still doesn't work for me I'm afraid  `ActionBar bar = mMainActivity.getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: @DJ-DOO any luck with this?

Comment: Very similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311612/how-to-catch-navigation-icon-click-on-toolbar-from-fragment

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 parts to your question:

1. Displaying the home button or back button:

Only to show home button:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Drawable homeMenu = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(homeMenu);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

To show a back arrow instead of home:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_material_white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

This only changes the image displayed.

2. To change the behaviour of the hamburger icon. In the activity where you want to change the behaviour of the home button, change the onclick of the menu item as shown to `onBackPressed()`:

   ```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int id = item.getItemId();
       switch (id) {
           case android.R.id.home:
               onBackPressed();
               return true;
           default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```

Leave it as it is for the normal navigation drawer. Hope this helps. This is how I have done for my app.

EDIT:
Remove the `mMainActivity.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` and then proceed with the 2nd part of the answer to do a `onBackPressed()` instead of the default hamburger functionality.

Comment: in my question I have stated that I have displayed the back arrow successfully and hidden the nav drawer icon..the problem is that it still opens and the nav drawer

Comment: I felt the way you are hiding the icon might be wrong. So, I have told you the way I handled the problem, and got it working. Do try it out.

Comment: yes but you're setting custom icons, I don't want to do that...other than that I don't see much difference between yours and mine, mine just shows the native back arrow

Comment: Ok. Read the second part of the answer. Remove the `mMainActivity.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` and then override the default hamburger functionality by adding `onBackPressed)`.

Comment: please see my edit.  I don't think the question was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's related but not quite to this question, but it could be helpful for somebody.

If you're using `NavigationComponent` and your `startDestination` fragment isn't (or shouldn't be) presented in the `NavigationView` menu then when you setting up your `AppBarConfiguration` you need to add `id` of your `startDestination` from your navigation graph:

```kotlin
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.menu_1, R.id.menu_2, R.id.menu_3), drawerLayout)
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you set something up incorrectly. Check out this tutorial, it may help you figure out what you're missing.

**EDIT** This is literally the first sentence in the link. For the `up` button to work, you need to set up parent activity in the manifest.

> To implement Up navigation, the first step is to declare which
>   activity is the appropriate parent for each activity. Doing so allows
>   the system to facilitate navigation patterns such as Up because the
>   system can determine the logical parent activity from the manifest
>   file.

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent)

Comment: but that has no reference to the nav drawer.  I have such navigation in other parts of my project, in different activities where I don't implement the nav drawer

Comment: This is meant to go with the suggestion to check out tutorial links. This is just a part of the tutorial - check out the tutorial itself first!

Comment: I did, that's what I'm talking about..there's no ref to the nav drawer in the tutorial

Comment: Fair enough, updated the first link to the beginning of the tutorial.