# Menu item from fragment can not trigger onOptionsItemSelected in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I want my activity to handle click on options menu items from fragment. and  menu item from fragment showed at activity's menu. However, onOptionsItemSelected is not triggered when I click the button. I followed instructions from [this]([1]: [(Deprecated) Fragment onOptionsItemSelected not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called)) but it not work. The code is as following:

```
Activity:

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_save:                      
                L.d("appointment: action save clicked");
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Fragment:

    @Override
    protected void doOnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.make_appointment_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

Menu:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".appointment.MakeAppointmentActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_save_btn"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

edit:

The fragment is added through transaction, I guess it was the culprit?

onCreate from Activity:

```
@Override
protected void doOnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.make_appointment_edit_title);
    }

    // 创建并初始化Fragment
    // savedInstanceState != null的时候，是指onSaveInstanceState被调用，此时UI部分会被恢复
    if (savedInstanceState == null && getIntent() != null) {
        String buyerName = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_BUYER_NAME);
        String listingTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_LISTING_TITLE);
        String appointmentStatus = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_APPOINTMENT_STATUS);
        float oppositeUserLatitude
                = (float) getIntent().getDoubleExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE, DEFAULT_UNKNOW_LATITUDE);
        float oppositeUserLongitude
                = (float) getIntent().getDoubleExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, DEFAULT_UNKNOW_LONGITUDE);

        MakeAppointmentFragment makeAppointmentFragment
                = MakeAppointmentFragment.newInstance(buyerName, listingTitle
                , appointmentStatus, oppositeUserLatitude, oppositeUserLongitude);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.make_appointment_fragment_placeholder, makeAppointmentFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` -----> comment this line in your fragment. I wonder if `doOnCreate` is available as an `@Override` method

Comment: doOnCreate is our custom hook method which will be called inside onCreate(). After comment setHasOptionsMenu(true), the button not show any more. @Skynet

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)` inside your `Fragment` if I do not miss remember. In case of you want to handle it in your `Activity`, cast and call `((YourActivity)getActivity). onOptionsItemSelected(item);` inside your overrided `onOptionsItemSelected` fragment.

Comment: According to Felixqk's answer to this question：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called  Activity has higher priority over fragment for onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: And I put a breakpoint in my fragment's onOptionsItemSelected, my code not paused there so I guess it will not work there.