# onMenuItemClick isn't being called - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

I have google map's activity, and a button that I want to inflate a popup menu.

This is the class:

```
public class NewMissionMapMainUser extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
```

And this is the onClick method that is called when my button is pushed:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

And that is the Code that is not being called.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_comedy:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Comedy Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_movies:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Movies Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item_music:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Music Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
    }
}
```

I've tried this link: 
[(Deprecated) Fragment onOptionsItemSelected not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035861/deprecated-fragment-onoptionsitemselected-not-being-called/24021438)

and `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

But i've changed the fragment to extent AppCompatActivity in order the action bar to be visible, so the line "setHasOptionsMenu(true);" can't be resolved.

Does someone knows how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: You never call `setOnMenuItemClickListener()` on the `PopupMenu`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're instantiating a `PopupMenu` dynamically, you need to provide it with the listener that will receive the click events. You should call `popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)`, assuming `this` is your Activity or Fragment.